# KPIs not up to date - Power Bi Reporting Server

Tags: powerbi, dataset, power-bi-report-server, kpi

I have an on-premises Power Bi Report Server. I have created several datasets, and schedule of refreshing datasets with new data every 5 minutes which is attached to datasets. I can see the datasets are updating as per the schedule attached to them but relative KPIs are not updating.

***How do I know the scheduler is working?*** 
 I checked it two ways.

1. On the **Schedules** page, *last run* and *next run* are updated.
2. When managing KPI and reattaching relative entity from the dataset then it updates and datasets are set to cache so it won't get the latest data when reattaching.

***What I have tried?***

- I tried refreshing the page.

Comment: Pbi desktop is a designer, you can refresh data manualy.
If you want automatic update, you have to publish your pbix file to power bi service and then scheduled the data refresh onto your dataset properties.

Comment: Dear @abaci
First thing first, I'm talking about **Power Bi Report Server** not **Power Bi Desktop** and these KPIs are added in Report Server.

The second thing, I have mentioned in the question is that schedules are created and attached to relative Datasets, and these Datasets are refreshing as per schedules but KPIs which are attached to Datasets are not updating, even if refreshing the page...